# Shift a fortnightly calendar by a week

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013, google-calendar, icalendar

I have a calendar with many events all of which repeat every 2 weeks. My problem is they are all out by a week. It is a Google Calendar, however I don't mind exporting it to another program then reimporting it. I have already tried to do this using Outlook and Google Calendar and couldn't find a way
Thanks.

Comment: Are the calendars (Outlook & Google) connected? Did you try to edit the series in the calendar it was originated in? Did you create the events? Keep in mind, if you don't own the events, you typically can't change them.

Comment: @CharlieRB No the calendars are not connected.  i can edit each individual  event however due to large number of events i dont want to. i do own the events and i created them

Comment: If you created them as a recurring series, then you should be able to edit the entire series to change all events in that series. Since there isn't an ability to change multiple series at once, you will have to change individual series you created.

Comment: Its a shame there is no way. I don't want to change over 50 reoccurring events

Comment: I understand your frustration. Unfortunately, in the time-frame to develop VBA to do this, you could already be done changing them individually.